# I want to remove index from codeigniter URL which have parameters

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to remove index from codeigniter URL which have parameters. Its not index.php but index function inside a controller. Currently my URL looks like this
`www.example.com/app1/index/param1/param2`

Here i wanna remove index from url so that URL would be

```
 www.example.com/app1/param1/param2
```

If i do so now it shows me error as 404 probably because it searhces for function param1 inside app1 controller

Comment: Alos chnage Allow All

Answer (score 2):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

try this .htaccess

if this code is not work then goto application/config/config.php

```
//  Find the below code
$config['index_page'] = "index.php"
//  Remove index.php
$config['index_page'] = "" 
//and 
//  Find the below code
$config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO"
//  Replace it as
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"
```

i hope it will be helpful

Comment: Ohh!! I see ..You have given me this code to remove index.php ...But thats not my problem...I already have index.php removed from my URL...Here i am explaining again
1) I have controller named app1
2) Inside app1 i have index function which has 2 parameters...
3) and becuase it has parameters i need to call it in URL like `www.example.com/app1/index/param1/param2`
4) From there i want to remove index so that my URL will be `www.example.com/app1/param1/param2`

Answer (score 1):

Hey please do following steps ,

application/config/config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php" to $config['index_page'] = ""
```

Root folder create .htaccess  file 
Note : Make sure create `.htaccess`  file not text file .

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  #RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

For working .htaccess  file please download here http://wikisend.com/download/862912/.htaccess

Note : In some cases the default setting for uri_protocol does not work properly. Just replace

```
$config['uri_protocol'] ="AUTO" to $config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"
```

Coming to the routings :

Codeigniter support two types of routings 
i)Wildcards
ii)Regular Expressions

I am giving you wildcards example please check bellow :

`application/config/routes.php` place this line

```
$route['/app1/index/(:num)/(:num)'] = "/app1/$1/$1";
```

For more information please refer the official document  http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html

Comment: Ohh!! I see ..You have given me this code to remove index.php ...But thats not my problem...I already have index.php removed from my URL...Here i am explaining again
1) I have controller named app1
2) Inside app1 i have index function which has 2 parameters...
3) and becuase it has parameters i need to call it in URL like `www.example.com/app1/index/param1/param2`
4) From there i want to remove index so that my URL will be `www.example.com/app1/param1/param2`

Comment: Please check answer i have updated , it my be helpful you

Comment: Sandeep Pujare  i hope above example will help you .

Answer (score 0):

### Try this:

**add route in** `application/config/routes.php` 
`$route['app1/(:any)/(:any)'] = "app1/index/$1/$2";`

**use in the** `App1 class` :

`public function index($param1, $param2) {
//do something
}`

Answer (score -1):

As your URL above, your controller looks like this:

```
<?php
class App1 extends CI_Controller
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  public function index($param1, $param2)
  {
    // ...your code here
  }
}
```

Try to change your controller again so you don't have to use `index` as a function.

```
<?php
class Apps extends CI_Controller
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }

 public function app1($param1, $param2)
 {
   // ... your code here
 }
```